# Trouble splitting an integral in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have trouble computing the numerator of this integral in Mathematica :

$$-\frac{3 \left(\int P(x,\kappa ) \left(Q^{(0,1)}(x,\kappa )+Q(x,\kappa )^2\right) \, dx\right)^2}{(\int P(x,\kappa ) \, dx)^2}$$

```
-((3*Integrate[P[x, κ]*(Q[x, κ]^2 + Derivative[0, 1][Q][x, κ]), x]^2) /
  Integrate[P[x, κ], x]^2)
```

I would like the integral of the sum to be split into the sum of the integrals so as to replace each integral by another expression. I have already tried using

```
Expand[Distribute //@ 
  -((3*Integrate[P[x, κ]*(Q[x, κ]^2 + Derivative[0, 1][Q][x, κ]), x]^2) /
    Integrate[P[x, κ], x]^2)]
```

but I ended up with

$$ -\frac{3 \left(\int P(x,\kappa ) Q^{(0,1)}(x,\kappa ) \, dx\right)^2}{(\int P(x,\kappa ) \, dx)^2}-\frac{3 \left(\int P(x,\kappa ) Q(x,\kappa )^2 \, dx\right)^2}{(\int P(x,\kappa ) \, dx)^2}, $$

which is not exactly what I want.

Does anyone know an easy way to split that integral properly?

#### Edit

I've tried

```
Map[
  Distribute,  
  Numerator[
    -((3*Integrate[P[x, κ]*(Q[x, κ]^2 + Derivative[0, 1][Q][x, κ]), x]^2) /
      Integrate[P[x, κ], x]^2)],
   ∞]
```

but I got

$$-3 \left(\left(\int P(x,\kappa ) Q^{(0,1)}(x,\kappa ) \, dx\right)^2+\left(\int P(x,\kappa ) Q(x,\kappa )^2 \, dx\right)^2\right),$$

Not much better.

Comment: Can you just use `Numerator`? By the way, please post code with proper *Mathematica* syntax, properly formatted in code blocks, rather than post in TeX. People like to copy and paste code from posts into their own copies of *Mathematica*.

Comment: OK I didn't know, sorry ! I've just edited my post. And I'll try your suggestion !

Comment: You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful for tips on posting code to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this:

```
(Integrate[ p[x, y] ( q1[x, y] + q2[x, y] ), {x, 0, 1}])^2/
  denominator  /. 
 Integrate[ p[x, y] Plus[a_, b_], c_] :> 
  Integrate[ p[x, y] a, c] + Integrate[ p[x, y] b, c]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes ! I didn't know that symbol :>. What is it for ? Thank you !!

Comment: Or `(Integrate[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ 
    Expand[p[x, y] (q1[x, y] + q2[x, y])])^2/denominator` or `(Integrate[p[x, y]*#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ (q1[x, y] + 
      q2[x, y]))^2/denominator`